# SharePoint adds +1 to time when I set it

Tags: 2007, development, date-time

I have an issue with SharePoint date time field.

Basically I have a date time field, and this field contains for example 19/12/2014 11:30:00. I would like to get this date and remove the time part, so i have then 19/12/2014 00:00:00, but when i set 2014-01-12T00:00:00Z, and i try to retrieve it later, i get 1/12/2014 1:00:00 AM, so i have no idea where this 1AM comes from.

Any idea?
Here is the script how i do it

```
$nDate = new-object System.DateTime ($dateTime.Year, $dateTime.Month, $dateTime.Day);
$date = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($nDate)
$item["DateTimeField"]= $nDate;
$item.SystemUpdate($false);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you retrieve it and parse it to ISO8601 again, to eliminate time zones etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime` is an extremely badly coded DateTime format function.

It has a hard requirement that the DateTime passed to it is in UTC as it just hardcoded adds Z as the zone designator.

So you have to convert your DateTime to UTC using `mySite.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.LocalTimeToUTC(date)` or some other method before calling it.

See [Converting Date and Time Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms197282%28v=office.12%29.aspx)